# Software SPI Isolation methods 2MHz

Tags: arduino, spi

I require some help with selecting the right components for SPI isolation.

The attached schematic is how I intended to isolate the SPI signal between my Arduino and the digital pot MCP41010, I have measured the clock frequency at around 2MHz, and have realized that the MCT6 isolator is far too slow for this function.

I require part from JLBCP basic parts range and have come across ADUM1201ARZ-RL7 a magnetic coupler, I believe this can handle the 2 MHz?

Q1) Is this a suitable isolator for spi?
Q2) Can you suggest how to integrate this into my schematic.

[image: MCT6 MCP41010]

I have updated the schematic following answers in the thread, to use a Texas Instruments/TI ISO7240MDWR

[image: Updated Schematic]

Comment: According to the data sheet, spi is a typical application.

Comment: Aren't published some evaluation boards from ADI? Or you can search Github for some users examples.

Comment: Why does the clock need to be so fast?  How often are you updating it?  You could probably slow it by a factor of 10 or more.

Comment: The speed is just the default speed of the fastSpi library I am using, I am updating once every 40ms

Comment: @MattRoberts It's generally recommended to wait a day or so before awarding an answer, to stimulate additional interest and answers on the site. (Silicon Labs has a similar series of isolator ICs to AD and TI, but there's no reason for me to post an answer since you already accepted one.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ADuM1201A](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM1200_1201.pdf) states on the front page of its data sheet this: -

> **SPI interface/data converter isolation**

However, it is limited to 2 Mbps and has only two channels. If you need the equivalent of MISO (SPI data back) then a 4 channel device like the [ADuM142D](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM140D_140E_141D_141E_142D_142E.pdf) is preferred because it has two outgoing and two incoming channels AND has a maximum guaranteed data speed of 150 Mbps. The application describes it as: -

> **Serial peripheral interface (SPI)/data converter isolation**

And it is good for 3 kV isolation (a little bit more than the 1201.)

Regarding your schematic, it's down to you to do this but there are a couple of things to bear in mind: -

- You need to provide an isolated supply for the isolated side of the chip. This means an extra component that provides this supply voltage.
- [This webpage](https://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11037#/p4938=%7C3&p4939=%7C1&p165=%7C4) lists all ADI's data isolation products and you might find a device that is good for SPI AND has an internal isolating supply such as the [ADuM5401/2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADuM5401W_5402W_5403W.pdf). I can't say if this is good for 2 Mbps - you'll have to check the data sheet: -

[image]

However, the page above does say: -

> **Quad dc-to-25 Mbps (NRZ) signal isolation channels**

Comment: JLPCB doesn't have stock of that part however based on your information I'm looking at ISO7240MDWR  by Texas Instruments.

https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/Texas-Instruments-TI-ISO7240MDW_C33323.pdf

They have an example of using the IC for SPI isolation.

I do have two isolated power supplies, A Meanwell isolated power supply for the main PCB and MCU.
The motor controller EM-282C will supply the 5V for the Digital Potentiometers, and the other side of the SPI ic.

Comment: @MattRoberts yes, they look good but don't forget they need an isolated supply feed.

Comment: Can you expand on that, please?
The input side from the MCU will be powered from an isolated supply, the output side will be powered by the 5V rail from the motor controller. 
The motor controller's power is common to the input side of the isolated PSU.
Is this enough?

Comment: Yes, that is completely enough @MattRoberts